# Which one should I use? -- "you { would have been / would have / were } paid double salary by me"

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one is correct to say?

> Hence i have made this adjestment, otherwise you would have been paid double Salary by me.

Or

> Hence i have made this adjestment, otherwise you would have paid double salary by me.

or

> Hence i have made this adjestment, otherwise you were paid double salary by me.

Comment: When you refer to yourself, ***I*** must be capitalised.

Comment: none of them :( Beginning with *hence* can be avoided. What you want to say exactly?

Comment: i want to say i have made adjustment in employees salary before paying it to him otherwise he would have got double/excess salary.

Comment: Okay, then go for this - *I have made this adjustment or else you'd have got the double salary.* Though I still don't get the context! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> **Therefore** *I* have made this *adjustment*, otherwise you **would have been** paid double salary by me.

I would use *therefore* although *hence* may be OK depending on locale.

Your second example indicates the employees paid the salary, so that is incorrect.

Your third example indicates you actually paid them before the adjustment, though the meaning here is kind of confused.